# Securing an MVC4 Application with OAuth from Separate .NET Core API using API Gateway

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, gateway, ocelot

I have an existing MVC4 application that I want to enhance by securing a specific endpoint using OAuth, with GitHub as the authentication provider. However, I would prefer not to implement the OAuth authentication logic directly in the MVC4 application since it's built on .NET 4.

My plan is to create a separate API using either .NET 6 or .NET 7, dedicated to handling the OAuth authentication process with GitHub. This API will be responsible for intercepting incoming traffic to the secured endpoint in the MVC4 application, performing the authentication, and, if the request is valid, redirecting it back to the original endpoint.

I am considering using an API gateway to facilitate this communication between the MVC4 application and the new .NET Core API. My goal is to make the integration seamless and maintain a clear separation of concerns between the MVC4 application and the authentication logic.

My question is, what would be the best approach to achieve this scenario? Are there any recommended API gateway solutions that can assist with routing traffic between the two applications and help ensure the security of the OAuth flow?

Any insights, code examples, or best practices would be greatly appreciated

i have tried some practice solution but still unsure. i am thinking to ask whether it is going to be a good solution or not